# How to get 50% relative to the screen size, using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what i have

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var y = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (y > 400 & y < 10000) {
    $("#font").css("top", 0 + $(window).scrollTop());
  }
});
```

The 400 should be 50% relative to screen size.
And the 10000 100%

Comment: You're just wanting to replace `400` with 50% of the screen's height? And `10000` you want replaced with 100% of the screen's height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`innerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight) (or use [`outerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/outerHeight) to get the height of the complete browser window) property of the window object to determin the screen size. This will return the height of the visible part of the page:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var y = $(window).scrollTop();

  var intViewportHeight = window.innerHeight;

  if (y > (intViewportHeight * 0.5) & y < (intViewportHeight * 1)) {
    $("#font").css("top", 0 + $(window).scrollTop());
  }
});
```

P.S: you obviously can omit the `* 1` part of the second formula. I just used it for clarification of the 100%